# add direction vector to 3d array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, normals

i have a 3d array with the shape of (3,11,11) this data represent 363 cells in the space i want to make a normal vector for that and per each position (points) instead of values as a number i can have directions look like this (0,0,1) or [0,0,1](i am trying to make mock normal vectors), how can i do that ?
so far i did

```
# Define the shape of the array
shape = (3, 11, 11)

# Create an array filled with zeros
normals = np.zeros(shape)

# Set the normals at z=0 to (0, 0, 1)
normal_value = np.array([0, 0, 1])
normals[0, :, :] = np.tile(normal_value, (11, 11, 1))
```

or

```
normal = np.zeros(mock_array.shape , dtype=object)
normal[0,:,:] = np.array([0,0,1], dtype=object)
print(normal[0,0,0])
```

or
using broad cast
nothing works

more about what i am trying to do:
each points it represents a cell that have three coordinates (x,y,z) i have these value as you know from my array shape(3,11,11) i have three layers of z and at first step i want to set direction vectors per each cell and where coordinates z = 0 i can set their values of x and y instated of numbers to array look like that (0,0,1) that suppose to be my normal vector

Comment: Can you clarify how many normal vectors you want to store? It seems from the question that you want 363 different normal vectors, but it looks like you want 11 normal vectors with 3 components each.

Comment: @Diego each points in represent a cell that have three coordinates (x,y,z) i have these value as you know from my array shape(3,11,11) i have three layers of z and at first step i want to set direction vectors per each cell and where coordinates z = 0 i can set their values of x and y  instated of numbers to array look like that (0,0,1) that suppose to be my normal vector

Comment: put this added info in your question.

Comment: Sill not clear for me. How many points do you have. 121 points, with 3 coordinates (x,y,z) each? So 363 coordinates together? And you want 121 normals, with 3 coordinates each (nx,ny,nz)? Or do 363 cells, with 363 normals. Which 3 coordinates (nx,ny,nz) per normal, so 1089 coordinates in all. Please reply with a straighforward answers. Do you want 121 normals, or 363? 121 or 363? And then edit your question accordingly (your question still says you want 363 normals, and still creates only 363 values array, when 363 normals mean 1089 values)

Comment: @chrslg thank you for comment 
i need 363 normals and with together 1089 at all

Comment: Is the `cross` product useful?  `np.cross` can work with 2 and 3d 'points'.

Comment: @sinajamshidi Then you need another axis. You have 3x11×11 normals. Each of them have 3 coordinates. Your `normals = np.zeros(shape)` should be `normals=np.zeros(shape+(3,))`. And then `normals[:,:,:]=[0,0,1]` does set all normals to `[1,0,1]`. `normals[a,b,c]`, which, if I understand correctly is the normal to cell `[a,b,c]`, with a∈[0,3[, b∈[0,11[, c∈[0,11[, is an array of 3 coordinates. `normals[a,b,c,0]` is x of normal. `normals[a,b,c,1]` is y, `normals[a,b,c,2]` is z. You can indifferently treat it as a 4d array of reals, or a 3d array of points

Comment: (or a 2d array of 1d array of points, or a 1d array of 2d array of points, ...but that is irrelevant). Note that since `normals` was intialized to 0, x and y are already 0. So initializing `normals[:,:,:]=[0,0,1]` does a redundant job (tho with a code more readable and closer to your attempt). In reality, all you need to change is  to put the `z` coordinate to 1. So `normals[:,:,:,2]=1`. Which can also be written `normals[...,2]=1`

Comment: As for how to computer another value that `[0,0,1]` for the normals, I dont' think that is your question. But I see that is what others try to answer. So I am in doubt. But you gave no indication about how we could do so. If you have 363 cells, and each of them are represented by a single scalar value, well, I don't know what that scalar value is, but I sure know that you can't compute the normal  without some geometric information about the cells position. 363 values aren't the positions of 363 cells.

Comment: Unless we are in 4D, and those 363 values are a manifold equation t=f(x,y,z). But we would need 1452 coordinates, not 369 :D